# Enumerador inválido ao tentar adicionar um filtro usando WFP pelo C#

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, firewall

Eu estou tentando portar [um código de c++](https://github.com/haywoodsloan/Get_Your_Act_Together) para c#. Meu objetivo é bloquear um site usando WFP. Depois de traduzir o código, parece que errei em algo porque ao adicionar um filtro recebo a mensagem "An enumerator is not valid" (FWP_E_INVALID_ENUMERATOR).

Já chequei o código várias vezes, incluindo debug junto com o código original e não consegui encontrar o que está errado. O código é muito longo porque contém declarações de estruturas, enumeradores e métodos de chamada à api do windows. Por isso, deixo abaixo apenas o trecho que está lançando a exception. O código completo pode ser encontrado no pastebin a partir [deste link](http://pastebin.com/GZFMtvcY).

```
var filterConditions = new List<FWPM_FILTER_CONDITION0_>();
filterConditions.Add(new FWPM_FILTER_CONDITION0_ {
    fieldKey = FWPM_CONDITION_IP_REMOTE_ADDRESS,
    matchType = FWP_MATCH_TYPE_.FWP_MATCH_EQUAL,
    conditionValue = new FWP_CONDITION_VALUE0_
    {
        type = FWP_DATA_TYPE_.FWP_V4_ADDR_MASK,
        v4AddrMask = site.ToIntPtr() // site é um objeto do tipo FWP_V4_ADDR_AND_MASK_
    }
});

var filterIn = new FWPM_FILTER0_ {
    subLayerKey = _subLayerGuid,
    layerKey = FWPM_LAYER_INBOUND_IPPACKET_V4,
    displayData = new FWPM_DISPLAY_DATA0_ { name = "Filter Name" },
    action = new FWPM_ACTION0_ { type = NativeConstants.FWP_ACTION_BLOCK },
    filterCondition = filterConditions.ToIntPtr(),
    numFilterConditions = (uint)filterConditions.Count,
    weight = new FWP_VALUE0_
    {
        type = FWP_DATA_TYPE_.FWP_UINT8,
        uint8 = 0x00
    }
};

var hr = NativeMethods.FwpmEngineOpen0(null, RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, ref _engineHandle);
Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR((int)hr);

hr = NativeMethods.FwpmSubLayerAdd0(_engineHandle, ref subLayer, IntPtr.Zero);
Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR((int)hr);

hr = NativeMethods.FwpmFilterAdd0(_engineHandle, ref filterIn, IntPtr.Zero, ref filterIn.filterId);
Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR((int)hr); // aqui recebo a exception FWP_E_INVALID_ENUMERATOR
```

Estou com esse problema a dias sem resolver. Postei uma questão no stackoverflow em inglês e recebi alguns downvotes então saibam que pesquisei bastante para portar esse código (não tem as referências necessárias no pinvoke.net) e, caso algo não ficar claro, por favor, comente que adiciono qualquer informação necessária.

Comment: Mas não é essa a função do `Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR`?

Comment: A função dele é realmente lançar exception caso o hr seja diferente de 0. Eu estou tentando descobrir porque o hr está diferente de 0. Estou desconfiado que tem algo de errado com a minha tradução de struct + union, mas ainda não achei o jeito certo de fazer.

Answer (score 0):

No final das contas, descobri o que era. O problema era na tradução das structs que contém union. Um exemplo é a struct abaixo:

```
typedef struct FWP_VALUE0_ {
  FWP_DATA_TYPE type;
  union {
    ;      // case(FWP_EMPTY)
    UINT8                 uint8;
    UINT16                uint16;
    UINT32                uint32;
    UINT64                *uint64;
    INT8                  int8;
    INT16                 int16;
    INT32                 int32;
    INT64                 *int64;
    float                 float32;
    double                *double64;
    FWP_BYTE_ARRAY16      *byteArray16;
    FWP_BYTE_BLOB         *byteBlob;
    SID                   *sid;
    FWP_BYTE_BLOB         *sd;
    FWP_TOKEN_INFORMATION *tokenInformation;
    FWP_BYTE_BLOB         *tokenAccessInformation;
    LPWSTR                unicodeString;
    FWP_BYTE_ARRAY6       *byteArray6;
  };
} FWP_VALUE0;
```

Ao traduzi-lo, simplesmente ignorei o union. Ficando o código em C# assim:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct FWP_VALUE0_
{
    public FWP_DATA_TYPE_ type;
    public byte uint8;
    public ushort uint16;
    public uint uint32;
    public System.IntPtr uint64;
    public byte int8;
    public short int16;
    public int int32;
    public System.IntPtr int64;
    public float float32;
    public System.IntPtr double64;
    public System.IntPtr byteArray16;
    public System.IntPtr byteBlob;
    public System.IntPtr sid;
    public System.IntPtr sd;
    public System.IntPtr tokenInformation;
    public System.IntPtr tokenAccessInformation;
    public System.IntPtr unicodeString;
    public System.IntPtr byteArray6;
}
```

O problema é que, pelo que entendi, ao fazer isso estou colocando cada um dos valores em sequência na memória. O union permite que todos os valores dentro dele ocupem a mesma posição, o que consequentemente só me permite usar um dos valores. Desta forma, a tradução correta ficaria assim:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct UnionType
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public byte uint8;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public ushort uint16;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public uint uint32;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public System.IntPtr uint64;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public byte int8;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public short int16;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public int int32;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public System.IntPtr int64;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public float float32;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public System.IntPtr double64;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public System.IntPtr byteArray16;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public System.IntPtr byteBlob;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public System.IntPtr sid;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public System.IntPtr sd;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public System.IntPtr tokenInformation;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public System.IntPtr tokenAccessInformation;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public System.IntPtr unicodeString;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
    public System.IntPtr byteArray6;
}
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct FWP_VALUE0_
{
    public FWP_DATA_TYPE_ type;
    public UnionType Union1;
}
```

Note o atributo StructLayout no UnionType como Explicit. O que me obriga a falar o offset de cada um dos valores. E aí, todos os valores têm o mesmo offset (0) o que faz com que todos ocupem a mesma posição.